# How to Extract an Array from a column to an Array in scala spark

Tags: arrays, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, etl

```
root
 |-- CC: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+-----------------------------+
|CC                           |
+-----------------------------+
|[Value1,Value2, null]|
+-----------------------------+
```

I have this Dataframe with just one value(which is an Array) in a column in dataframe. I want to extract it to an Array

```
val c=b.select('CC.getItem(0))
```

gives the first value, `getItem(1)` gives the second value.

Is there a way to extract that whole Array into a normal array.

Comment: Try `val c = b.select("CC").as[Seq[String]].collect`

Comment: @blackbishop thank you for helping. It still makes the array of a list.  c: Array[Seq[String]] = Array(List(Value1,Value2, null)). I was wondering if it possible to have it as a: Array[String] = Array(Value1,Value2, null)

Comment: each sub-list corresponds to a row in your dataframe. If you want to flatten use `.flatten` after collect

Comment: OMG. You are the best. I spent so much time, I totally forgot about the flatten concept. Thank you very much kind stranger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
val arry = b.select("CC").rdd.map(row => row.getAs[Seq[String]](0)).collect().flatten
```